# Fastcgi params configuring owncloud with nginx

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, fastcgi, owncloud

So there's [a site](https://pestmeester.nl/index.html) and I'm configuring my Ubuntu server. I've done it once about 2 years ago but a lot has changed a lot since then. For example, there's php8.0 now and owncloud doesn't support it yet. Anyway, I have php7.4 and I'm trying to configure my `/etc/nginx/sites-available/mydomainname.com` config file (of course with my real domain name) but I can't make it work. I've tried so much fastcgi parameter example and none of them worked. [The site I mentioned has also an example](https://pestmeester.nl/index.html#8.3) and it worked 2 years ago but now it doesn't. I get the same error: FastCGI sent in stderr: `"Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream`.

Can anybody help me? What's wrong with this config?

```
location ~ [^/].php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?.php)(/.*)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
```

Comment: "Primary script unknown" means the value of SCRIPT_FILENAME does not point to a file that PHP can read. Check your `fastcgi_params` file, and the value of the `root` directive which is inherited by that `location`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I needed to put this line and now it works `fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME         $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;`

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem if anybody need this someday. I checked the fastcgi_params file in /etc/nginx/ but I didn't see that there were a missing line. This:
`fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME         $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;`
Thanks for Richard Smith for his help.